# Only use Carousel of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I am now using Semantic UI without including Bootstrap as there are some conflicts among them. But I quite like the Carousel function of bootstrap. Can I optionally include it in my project? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can customize bootstrap here:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Just select the Carousel in Javascript components category and Carousel functionnality in jquery plugins.
Then download the files and include them in your project.

Comment: I just followed these instructions to generate a carousel-only library and it's broken.  Turns out the CSS and their recommended usage don't match.  Some class names in the CSS file don't match what they tell you to use in the Carousel documentation (like "carousel-item" vs "item", or "carousel-control-prev" vs. "carousel-control left").  Unless I missed something, this is totally busted and you need to figure it out on your own.  Pretty poor job by the BS folks.

Comment: 6 years later and this happened to me. Problem was that the customise page was targeting version 3.4 and I had the bootstrap html from version 5 of the carousel. What I ended up doing was downloading version 4 of the css and removing everything above and below the .carousel classes, targeted version 4 of the js via a CDN and it all worked fine then.