# Bootstrap CSS/Javascript For Carousel Only

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap CSS/Javascript For Carousel Only

Currently using Carousel With Controls

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
     <video controls="true">
      <source src="www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bGNuRtlqAQ" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <video controls="true">
       <source src="www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bGNuRtlqAQ" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Anyone have CSS Codes and Javascript Codes for this function ? (Don't want the whole file as it would conflict with my main CSS)

Comment: What do you mean Javascript code for this function ? What exactly do you need ? Be more specific please.

Comment: Okay , so currently i have implemented "Bootstrap Carousel" for my page , but it required additional CSS and js file to run it . 

But if I link "Bootstrap CSS and JS" it will conflicted with my orignal CSS file and cause half of my page content messed up

Comment: I don't think so, since you use bootstrap classes for this carousel only, it will only effect your carousel styling, not your other hard coded css styling. Unless you use bootstrap class naming in your own css file.

Comment: It will change my "width" , image height and so on

Comment: You do not have to use bootstrap styling for the image to use the carousel and its functions. You can basically change the class name of the img to something else and use your own styling in your css file. Or just delete the w-100 part of the bootstrap class name.

Comment: Yeah , but currently i have 2 different "carousel" in the same page 
1st carousel is for video and image
2nd carousel is for product listing (e-commerce element) ,  and i only able to use 1 carousel, as if i add "external" css , the 2nd carousel stopped working . if i didn't add the external css , 1st carousel stopped working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205496/discussion-between-greenboxgoolu-and-bora-sumer).

Comment: Simply put your overriding css after the bootstrap css. Also you can grab separate pieces of Bootstrap code mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991987/only-use-carousel-of-bootstrap which mentions this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/ or click the top bar for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: To call multiple instances use a unique id or class and then fire it with the bootstrap carousel js callback.

Comment: please explain  your question  clear you want change carousel style and customize or you have class with this name in your css ? first explain this

Comment: @greenboxgoolu, can you please confirm that you are using jQuery. Is that fine if I can suggest any jQuery only plugin for carousel?

Comment: can you please add a comment for the Answer, if it works or not?

Comment: Sorry for late reply , will update when back to work

Answer (score 7):

I found an old [Pen](https://codepen.io/erinmc/pen/eXXwvj?editors=1010) and customized it a bit to suit your needs.

Here is a standalone Bootstrap 4 Carousel with no dependencies (even jQuery):

**Update 1:** Added images source and set the default height to `70vh`

**Update 2:** Added video - iframe support. It seems that SOF is not allowing video/iframe backgrounds so here is the a [codepen](https://codepen.io/awran5/pen/WNbyGyR) source.

```js
const carousel = document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls')
const items = carousel.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
let currentItem = 0;
let isActive = true;

function setCurrentItem(index) {
  currentItem = (index + items.length) % items.length;
}

function hideItem(direction) {
  isActive = false;
  items[currentItem].classList.add(direction);
  items[currentItem].addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    this.classList.remove('active', direction);
  });
}

function showItem(direction) {
  items[currentItem].classList.add('next', direction);
  items[currentItem].addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    this.classList.remove('next', direction);
    this.classList.add('active');
    isActive = true;
  });
}

document.getElementById('carouselPrev').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (isActive) {
    hideItem('to-right');
    setCurrentItem(currentItem - 1);
    showItem('from-left');
  }
});

document.getElementById('carouselNext').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (isActive) {
    hideItem('to-left');
    setCurrentItem(currentItem + 1);
    showItem('from-right');
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner>.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  animation: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  height: 70vh; /* Set your height */
}

.carousel-item>.carousel-img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70vh; /* same height */
  height: auto;
}
.carousel-item.carousel-video {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  /* uncomment the following line if you want to prevent mouse (or touch) clicks */
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}
.carousel-inner>.active,
.carousel-inner>.next {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-inner>.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner>.to-left {
  animation-name: left;
}

.carousel-inner>.from-right {
  animation-name: right;
}

.carousel-inner>.to-right {
  animation-name: right;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.carousel-inner>.from-left {
  animation-name: left;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 15%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel-control-prev,
  .carousel-control-next {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.carousel-control-prev:hover,
.carousel-control-prev:focus,
.carousel-control-next:hover,
.carousel-control-next:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  right: 0;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: no-repeat 50% / 100% 100%;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5L4.25 4l2.5-2.5L5.25 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5L3.75 4l-2.5 2.5L2.75 8l4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
}

.sr-only-focusable:active,
.sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- YouTube Video -->
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <iframe class="carousel-video" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QEbuc3cgmsI" frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <!-- add "?autoplay=1" at the end of the URL for autoplay i.e. https://www.youtube.com/embed/QEbuc3cgmsI?autoplay=1 -->
    </div>
    <!-- Local Video -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <video class="carousel-video" autoplay muted loop playsinline preload="metadata"
        poster="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.jpg">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <!-- Image -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="carousel-img" alt="Second slide" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1920x1080">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a id="carouselPrev" class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a id="carouselNext" class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply 

But it does not "mobile friendly"  , any idea how do i make it mobile friendly ?

Comment: @greenboxgoolu Its "mobile friendly" at some level but it will be determined by your images height and if you're going to add content to it. Would you give a link to see what's your desired carousel form? I've edited the answer and set the default height to `70vh`.

Comment: but what if it was video ? <video> ( edited on first post )

Comment: Same concept, You'll just need to add some extra CSS. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317276/fitting-video-in-slider-bootstrap-4-0)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , will update it when back to work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bundler like Webpack, your could import and compile individual components as explained in [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to use bootstrap for your website for other sections except slider section then I have suggest you to use external library only for slider because from bootstrap libraries it is not easy to filter only slider code.

This is the reference website link for only slider: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

This slier is easy to customize and there are so many options to set slider properties using Jquery.

I hope this will help you to solve your problem and this is only SLider Library so it will not conflict your main css so you can easily add this library to your code.

Thank you...

Comment: hey did you review this answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite your code. Because The Bootstrap is a pattern of World Wide Web 2.0. Your Site will be looked pretty with all functions of The Bootstrap. Please download the Full Bootstrap package and use it all and do not something. Use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/ .It is begun the post information era after ten years - The Bootstrap will have been finalized. And finally, The program is not the data size.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what Nathaniel is suggesting you do.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Of course in your case you are using Bootstrap, but hopefully this visual helps you understand that part of Nathaniels recommendation.

Then you just grab the Bootstrap class names you need and you can implement that in the HTML you will write inside your JavaScript file.

```
const carouselTemplate = (videoDetail) => {
   return `<div class=“carousel-item-active”>
            <video controls=“true”>
              <source src=“${videoDetail.id}”>
            </video>
          </div>`;
}
```

Then you want to render that HTML to the DOM, so you can create an element in your HTML like so:

```
<div id="carousel"></div>
```

and then back in your JavaScript file you do the following:

```
document.querySelector('#carousel').innerHTML = carouselTemplate(response.data);
```

That `response.data` you pass in can be the `videoDetail` data object which I am assuming you may have fetched via:

```
const onVideoSelect = async video => {
  const response = await axios.get('http://www.youtube.com/');
  document.querySelector('#carousel').innerHTML = carouselTemplate(response.data)
}
```

There are probably some params object missing in that `axios.get()` for YouTube to fetch a video of a specific id, but I do not presently have the YouTube API docs in front of me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same desire for Bootstrap Carousel (3.x) without all the rest of Bootstrap. I put up a small git repo and instructions for how to use it here: https://github.com/mdlavin/bootstrap-carousel-standalone